# Linux Sort command

Tags: linux, sorting

I would like to know which sorting algorithm the linux SORT command uses?

Comment: Here is the source code for it - I think.
http://csourcesearch.net/c/fid09A5B659DB92C4AE62E66D3F480BE5AC106E5913.aspx?s=sort#L1

Comment: When you looked at the source, what did you learn?

Answer (score 11):

#### mergesort

It<sup>1</sup> uses *mergesort* rather than *quicksort* or *heapsort* for two reasons:

- mergesort is a ***[stable sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability)*** and typically the efficient quicksort implementations are not
- while it may do more swaps or moves it does fewer comparisons and so tends to work better with text input

---

<sup>***1.*** Linux distros are free to choose their own sort utility but I imagine virtually all use [GNU sort](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/textutils/coreutils_28.html) so I have described that.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answers to all guys.
Will check the merge sort now.

Answer (score 7):

An External R-Way merge sort according to [Algorithm details of UNIX Sort Command.](http://vkundeti.blogspot.com/2008/03/tech-algorithmic-details-of-unix-sort.html)  Found via [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930044/why-unix-sort-command-could-sort-a-very-large-file).