# Best way to pipe output of Linux sort

Tags: python

I would like process a file line by line. However I need to sort it first which I normally do by piping:

```
sort --key=1,2 data |./script.py.
```

What's the best to call sort from within python? Searching online I see `subprocess` or the `sh` module might be possibilities?  I don't want to read the file into memory and sort in python as the data is very big.

Comment: FYI: sort has to read the file in memory

Comment: Not exactly. Linux sort is very clever about it and can sort massive files even bigger than RAM by using an external memory sorting algorithm. Seehttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/930044/how-could-the-unix-sort-command-sort-a-very-large-file .

Comment: Maybe sort does, maybe it doesn't have to read the file into memory, but then again, why does Python? (If `sort` can be clever, so can Python.)

Comment: @kojiro Because there is no external memory sort module for python afaik. There is nothing stopping someone writing one of course.

Comment: @kojiro, but external sor tin linux already wirtten but you have to write it for py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its easy. Use subprocess.Popen to run sort and read its stdout to get your data.

```
import subprocess
myfile = 'data'
sort = subprocess.Popen(['sort', '--key=1,2', myfile],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in sort.stdout:
    your_code_here
sort.wait()
assert sort.returncode == 0, 'sort failed'
```

Comment: What does sort.wait() do? It looks like sort would have to have finished before it got to that line in any case.

Comment: The for loop reads the process stdout until the process closes it (usually on process exit but the process is free do do an early close if it wants to). The wait() call waits for process exit and gets its return code. This is important on linux as it removes the zombie process from the system process table.

Answer (score 0):

<s>I believe sort will read all data in memory, so I'm not sure you will won anything</s> but you can use `shell=True` in [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) and use pipeline

```
>>> subprocess.check_output("ls", shell = True)
'1\na\na.cpp\nA.java\na.php\nerase_no_module.cpp\nerase_no_module.cpp~\nWeatherSTADFork.cpp\n'
>>> subprocess.check_output("ls | grep j", shell = True)
'A.java\n'
```

> **Warning**
>   Invoking the system shell with shell=True can be a security hazard if combined with untrusted input. See the warning under Frequently Used Arguments for details.

Comment: Thanks. Sort will not read the whole file into memory.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930044/how-could-the-unix-sort-command-sor‌​t-a-very-large-file. .

Answer (score 0):

I think [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python) will answer your question

The answer I prefer, from @Eli Courtwright is (all quoted verbatim):

Here's a summary of the ways to call external programs and the advantages and disadvantages of each:

1. `os.system("some_command with args")` passes the command and arguments to your system's shell.  This is nice because you can actually run multiple commands at once in this manner and set up pipes and input/output redirection.  For example,
   `os.system("some_command < input_file | another_command > output_file")`
   However, while this is convenient, you have to manually handle the escaping of shell characters such as spaces, etc.  On the other hand, this also lets you run commands which are simply shell commands and not actually external programs.
   http://docs.python.org/lib/os-process.html
2. `stream = os.popen("some_command with args")` will do the same thing as `os.system` except that it gives you a file-like object that you can use to access standard input/output for that process.  There are 3 other variants of popen that all handle the i/o slightly differently.  If you pass everything as a string, then your command is passed to the shell; if you pass them as a list then you don't need to worry about escaping anything.
   http://docs.python.org/lib/os-newstreams.html
3. The `Popen` class of the `subprocess` module.  This is intended as a replacement for `os.popen` but has the downside of being slightly more complicated by virtue of being so comprehensive.  For example, you'd say
   `print Popen("echo Hello World", stdout=PIPE, shell=True).stdout.read()`
   instead of
   `print os.popen("echo Hello World").read()`
   but it is nice to have all of the options there in one unified class instead of 4 different popen functions.
   http://docs.python.org/lib/node528.html
4. The `call` function from the `subprocess` module.  This is basically just like the `Popen` class and takes all of the same arguments, but it simply wait until the command completes and gives you the return code.  For example:
   `return_code = call("echo Hello World", shell=True)`
   http://docs.python.org/lib/node529.html
5. The os module also has all of the fork/exec/spawn functions that you'd have in a C program, but I don't recommend using them directly.

The `subprocess` module should probably be what you use.

Comment: Thanks but I thought shell=True was deprecated.

Comment: you'd probably know better than me -- I'm still a Python beginner.