# How to sort a large file on two levels efficiently?

Tags: perl, unix, sorting

I have a very large file, over 100GB (many billions of lines), and I would like to conduct a two-level sort as quick as possible on a unix system with limited memory. This will be one step in a large perl script, so I'd like to use perl if possible.

So, how can I do this? My data looks like this:

```
A    129
B    192
A    388
D    148
D    911
A    117
```

...But for billions of lines. I need to first sort by letter, and then by number. Would it be easier to use a unix sort, like...

```
sort -k1,2 myfile
```

Or can I do this all in perl somehow? My system will have something like 16GB ram, but the file is about 100GB.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Are all the numbers 3 digits? If not, are they right-aligned? If both these conditions hold (all 3 digits or right-aligned) then you only need a single-level textual sort.

Comment: @Jim, thanks for the comment. No, the numbers range from 1-100,000,000 and these are just two, non-adjacent columns of a larger spreadsheet (genome sequencing data)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The UNIX `sort` utility can handle sorting large data (e.g. larger than your working 16GB of RAM) by creating temporary working files on disk space.

So, I'd recommend simply using UNIX `sort` for this as you've suggested, invoking the option `-T tmp_dir`, and making sure that `tmp_dir` has enough disk space to hold all of the temporary working files that will be created there.

By the way, this is discussed in a [previous SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930044/how-could-the-unix-sort-command-sort-a-very-large-file)

Answer (score 1):

The UNIX `sort` is the best option for sorting data of this scale. I would recommend use fast compression algorithm `LZO` for it. It is usually distributed as `lzop`. Set big sort buffer using `-S` option. If you have some disk faster than then where you have default `/tmp` set also `-T`. Also, if you want sort by a number you have to define sorting number sorting as second sorting field. So you should use line like this for best performance:

```
LC_ALL=C sort -S 90% --compress-program=lzop -k1,1 -k2n
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue!
After searching a lot and since i did not want any dependency on the shell (UNIX) to make it portable on windows i came up with the below solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Sort qw(sort_file);
my $src_dic_name = 'C:\STORAGE\PERSONAL\PROJECTS\perl\test.txt';
sort_file({k => 1, t=>"    ", I => $src_dic_name, o => $src_dic_name.".sorted"});
```

I know this is a old post but updating it with the solution so that it is easy to find.

[Documentation here](http://search.cpan.org/~cnandor/File-Sort-1.01/Sort.pm)