# Use find to pass argument to program with parallel

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am trying to pass multiple arguments to a program.

```
find binaries/$package/lib -iname "*.txt" | parallel java -jar proguard/proguard.jar @obfuscateprofile -injars $package.jar -outjars binaries/$package/$pacakge.jar -libraryjars {}
```

I can use echo as a demonstration:

```
find binaries/derbypro/lib -iname "*.txt" | parallel echo -libraryjars {}
```

I want the program to get multiple `-libraryjars` arguments for each file found with `find`. For example, if I have a directory with the following files in it:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

And I run the command, I want it to be equivalent to running the program like this:

```
programname -libraryjars file1.txt -libraryjars file2.txt -libraryjars file3.txt
```

But what I get instead is this:

```
programname -libraryjars file1.txt
programname -libraryjars file2.txt
programname -libraryjars file3.txt
```

So when I run

```
find binaries/derbypro/lib -iname "*.txt" | parallel echo -libraryjars {}
```

I get

```
-libraryjars file1.txt
-libraryjars file2.txt
-libraryjars file3.txt
```

So it is executing multiple `echo` programs. If I specify the number of parameters I am expecting with `-N 3` it works fine, but I don't know how many files `fine` will find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
programname -libraryjars `find binaries/$package/lib -name '*.txt' | xargs | sed 's/ / -libraryjars /g'`
```

I assume the number of .txt files is not huge.

Comment: Right now, I have 25 files, it seems to work fine, any idea what the limit could be?

Answer (score 1):

parallel follows a map-reduce paradigm. it aims to separate large tasks into small ones and assign them to multiple programs, which doesn't satisfy your requirement.

For example, a simple map-reduce `wc` program using parallel would be:

```
cat XXX | parallel --block 10M --pipe wc -l | awk 'BEGIN{count=0;}{count = count+ $1;} END{print count;}'
```

Please check: [How to write multicore sorting using GNU Parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27970953/how-to-write-multicore-sorting-using-gnu-parallel) for more details.

In your case, what you want is `programname -libraryjars file1.txt -libraryjars file2.txt -libraryjars file3.txt`

you could concatenate your parameters like this:

```
find binaries/derbypro/lib -iname "*.txt" | awk '{params = params " " "-libraryjars " $1;} END {print params;}' | xargs programname
```

to run your program

Answer (score 0):

you might ty this that uses bash function to decorate any result line from find with -libraryjars prefix :

```
find binaries/$package/lib -iname "*.txt" |  { while read LINE; do echo "-libraryjars $LINE"; done;} | xargs java -jar proguard/proguard.jar @obfuscateprofile -injars $package.jar -outjars binaries/$package/$package.jar
```

limitation is that it is can be fooled with files containing spaces or non orthodox characters ( seen as delimiters for xargs ).