# Remove a duplicate line in text-file that has one word change per line

Tags: bash, shell, awk

```
somethingsame,somethingsame_usage,2015-11-30 01:00:00,0
somethingsame,somethingsame_usage,2015-11-30 02:00:00,0
somethingsame,somethingsame_usage,2015-11-30 03:00:00,0
somethingelse,somethingelse_usage,2015-11-30 01:00:00,0
somethingelse,somethingelse_usage,2015-11-30 02:00:00,0
somethingelse,somethingelse_usage,2015-11-30 03:00:00,0
```

I want to remove lines and have end product:

```
somethingsame,somethingsame_usage,2015-11-30 02:00:00,0
somethingelse,somethingelse_usage,2015-11-30 03:00:00,0
```

The only thing changing is the time (per data i.e. somethingsame vs. somethingelse) that is different but everything else is the same. It does not matter which line/time I keep; I just want only one.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your post could be improved if you've showed us what code have you tried so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't care what order the lines are output, you can do this with `sort`, using the `-u` (unique) command-line flag, which includes only one instance of a set of unique lines.

Unlike `uniq`, `sort -u` compares only the part of the line defined by the `-k` options, so you can specify precisely which fields are to be counted as part of the uniqueness test. So in this case, you could use:

```
sort -u -t, -k1,2
```

where `-t,` means that the field delimiter is a comma, and `-k1,2` means that the "key" consists of everything from the first character in the first field to the last character in the second field.

Note that the `-k` argument is a range, not a list: `-k1,3` would mean the first three fields, while `-k2` would mean "from the second field to the end of the line".

Comment: Minahil, if your input file is not sorted, this is a very good solution. If your input is sorted, calling sort again on it can be redundant and costly in terms of processing time. Depends on the whether you have a few KB or a few GB of input.

Comment: @RamónGilMoreno: The sort utility is well optimized for large files which are already sorted.

Comment: I had read this question in the past http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930044/how-could-the-unix-sort-command-sort-a-very-large-file and I don't have any doubt sort will deal wilth large files, but stills looks like consuming a big bunch of resources. IMHO.

Comment: my input is not sorted and I'm dealing with around 500,000 lines, what's another solution, this seems to work.

Comment: @Minahil: If your input is not sorted and you want to remove duplicates even if they are not consecutive, this is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

idiomatic `awk` solution is as follows

```
$ awk -F, '!a[$1]++' log

somethingsame,somethingsame_usage,2015-11-30 01:00:00,0
somethingelse,somethingelse_usage,2015-11-30 01:00:00,0
```

picks up the first instance.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution uses `awk`, but it is not my favourite (will write it in a separate answer).

What it does?

Line by line, simply keeps track of previous line's relevant values (first two fields, stored in variables `previous1` and `previous2`). These values are updated at the end of processing the line.

Upon finding a line where current values (`current1` and `current2`) are different from the previous ones, simply call `print $0` to print the whole line.

I also configure the fields separator (`FS` value) to be comma.

You can build more elaborate criteria to decide if two lines are equals or not and if the new line needs printing.

Here is the complete console dump:

```
$ cat input.txt 
somethingsame,somethingsame_usage,2015-11-30 01:00:00,0
somethingsame,somethingsame_usage,2015-11-30 02:00:00,0
somethingsame,somethingsame_usage,2015-11-30 03:00:00,0
somethingelse,somethingelse_usage,2015-11-30 01:00:00,0
somethingelse,somethingelse_usage,2015-11-30 02:00:00,0
somethingelse,somethingelse_usage,2015-11-30 03:00:00,0
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS="," } { current1 = $1; current2 = $2; if ((previous1 != current1) && (previous2 != current2)) { print $0 } previous1 = current1; previous2 = current2; }' input.txt
somethingsame,somethingsame_usage,2015-11-30 01:00:00,0
somethingelse,somethingelse_usage,2015-11-30 01:00:00,0
$
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a different solution using `uniq` given that your input file is already sorted.

Note that the hack is that I simply strip the irrelevant part of the line, thus it won't appear in the result:

```
$ cat input.txt
somethingsame,somethingsame_usage,2015-11-30 01:00:00,0
somethingsame,somethingsame_usage,2015-11-30 02:00:00,0
somethingsame,somethingsame_usage,2015-11-30 03:00:00,0
somethingelse,somethingelse_usage,2015-11-30 01:00:00,0
somethingelse,somethingelse_usage,2015-11-30 02:00:00,0
somethingelse,somethingelse_usage,2015-11-30 03:00:00,0
$ cat input.txt | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "," } { print $1 "," $2 }' | uniq
somethingsame,somethingsame_usage
somethingelse,somethingelse_usage
$
```