# How sort piped into uniq works in unix

Tags: unix, uniq

In the following:

`cat file | cut -f 1,5,6 | sort | uniq`

Is intuitive to me to think that `uniq` needs to know the whole dataset before proceeding.
From [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43602042/internal-working-of-sort-uniq-command-when-input-is-piped-or-redirected-to-it) I understand that `sort` **does** write temporary files into disk for long sets of data.

Does `uniq` writes temporary files into disk for long datasets? Where?

Thank you!

Comment: It only needs to look at two lines - current and next. Just reads lines in a loop; no need to get all the input before starting to do its thing.

Comment: @Shawn , then `uniq -c` uses a different algorithm? Also, then `uniq` starts ONLY after sort completes?

Comment: Nah, no different; just keep track of the length of runs of duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uniq` only needs to read a line at a time and compare the current line to the previous one; it can start working as soon as it starts getting lines; no need to read all input before producing any output.

Basically, it just needs to read a line, and compare it to the previous line. If they're the same, increment a counter. If not, print the previous line (With count if requested). Then save the current line as the previous, and repeat.

Here's a bare bones version written in C you can use as an example:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  _Bool show_count = 0;

  if (argc == 2 && strcmp(argv[1], "-c") == 0) {
    show_count = 1;
  } else if (argc > 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-c]\n", argv[0]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  char *prev = NULL;
  size_t prev_len = 0;
  int count = 1;
  while (1) {
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t line_len = 0;
    ssize_t len = getline(&line, &line_len, stdin);
    if (len < 0) {
      if (feof(stdin)) {
        break;
      } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't read input: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
    } else {
      if (prev) {
        if (strcmp(line, prev) == 0) {
          count++;
        } else {
          if (show_count) {
            printf("%7d ", count);
          }
          fwrite(prev, 1, prev_len, stdout);
          count = 1;
        }
        free(prev);
      }
    }
    prev = line;
    prev_len = len;
  }

  if (prev) {
    if (show_count) {
      printf("%7d ", count);
    }
    fwrite(prev, 1, prev_len, stdout);
    free(prev);
  }

  return 0;
}
```